# Что делать с кодировкой страниц?

Tags: html, кодировка, битрикс

Работаю в `Bitrix`. Создал сайт в кодировке `UTF-8`, затем скопировал на него шаблон, созданный в однобайтовой кодировке, в результате чего, все русские буквы превратились в знаки вопроса. Есть вариант решения проблемы, не пересохраняя все 3000 файлов в нужной кодировке?

Comment: перекодируйте, скриптом, благо даже в 10ке есть баш режим. 21век, долой 8ми битные кодировки.

Comment: Либо если пользуетесь какой-либо IDE, то можно перекодировать все там. 
Например phpstorm - в настройках выставляете нужную кодировку для проекта, применяете изменения и заливаете обратно на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

На английской версии есть похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4544843/4369563

Проверьте что исходная кодировка windows-1251, пути к шаблонам (команда создаст новый шаблон в исправленной кодировке)

```
cd /home/www/bitrix/templates/original_template
mkdir /home/www/bitrix/templates/new_template
find . -type f -exec iconv -f windows-1251 -t utf-8 "{}" -o /home/www/bitrix/templates/new_template/"{}" \;
```

В новом шаблоне проверьте meta теги с указанием кодировки.
Кроме того возможно вам нужно перекодировать только php файлы (или даже только lang файлы). В таком случае можно воспользоваться опцией `-iregex`